# OSError [Errno 13] Permission denied on file upload

Tags: python, django

On Django when i submit a modelform that has an image field, this error is raised when saving the model, when saving the uploaded file

The model simple have a line

```
student(model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='/photos')
```

This error is raised when submiting the form

```
OSError(13, 'Permission denied')
```

Occurs in the model save() method util this point

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py in _save
                fd = os.open(full_path, flags, 0o666)
```

The part code that raise the error is

```
flags = (os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL |
                         getattr(os, 'O_BINARY', 0))
                # The current umask value is masked out by os.open!
fd = os.open(full_path, flags, 0o666)
```

Check this line in Django source code :
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/storage.py#L221

variables contents

```
e : OSError(13, 'Permission denied')
name : u'photos/10703514_652406348206730_7516458761930522613_n.jpg'
self : <django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage object at 0x3654550>
content : <ImageFieldFile: 10703514_652406348206730_7516458761930522613_n.jpg>
flags : 193
directory : u'/var/www/pr5/mediafolder/photos'
full_path : u'/var/www/pr5/mediafolder/photos/10703514_652406348206730_7516458761930522613_n.jpg'
```

You think that it's a permission problem but even with :

```
chmod -R 777 *
```

i get the same error, so it's not a permission problem but something else limiting

**/var/www/pr5/** is the project directory

User and Group are cherokee:cherokee for all files in directory under it

```
chown -R cherokee:cherokee *
```

and chmod is 777 (should be 770) for all too

I'm using cherokee as Web server for serving static and media files
runing on a socket with this command

```
/usr/bin/python2 /var/www/pr5/manage.py runfcgi method=threaded socket=/tmp/djangoche.socket daemonize=False protocol=scgi
```

settings.py

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 770
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS =770


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/mediafolder/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/staticfolder/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
BASE_DIR + STATIC_URL,
)
```

Trace is

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost/student/new

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'school')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/pr5/school/views.py" in post
  313.             studentvar=stu.save()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  457.                              construct=False)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_instance
  103.         instance.save()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  590.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  618.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  699.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  732.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  921.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  919.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  877.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
  301.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
  89.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in save
  51.         name = self._save(name, content)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in _save
  222.                     fd = os.open(full_path, flags, 0o666)

Exception Type: OSError at /student/new
Exception Value: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/pr5/mediafolder/10703514_652406348206730_7516458761930522613_n.jpg'
```

I've searched other questions but nothing solved this issue.

The form is a classic one simpy save instance on form valid

```
class NewStudent(View):

    student_form = modelform_factory(Student,exclude=())

    def get(self, request,pk=None):

        stu=self.student_form() 
        return render(request,'school/student_new.html',{'form1': stu)
    def post(self, request):

        stu=self.student_form(request.POST,request.FILES)

        if stu.is_valid() :
            studentvar=stu.save()

            return redirect(to='student_detail',pk=studentvar.pk)

        return render(request,'school/student_new.html',{'form1': stu)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Executing with a socket created on tmp directory is causing the issue**

I fixed this problem by moving the socket file :

from /tmp/djangoche.socket to /var/www/pr5/server.socket

Problem occured with WSGI and uWSGI config cases

You can also try this in addition if not fixed

1. (for cherokee server only) Uncheck the "Check file" in Cherokee adminstration for the virtual serveur who hande the WSGI (or like) , this is suited for file based scripts like php and it cause lot of problems our case.
   This option is under **Handler** tab in **Common CGI Options** section
2. Secondely (optional is worked with the first fix) , add to your WSGI.py file :

   import sys
   sys.path.append('/path/to/project')
   sys.path.append('/path/to/project/projectname')